# Why the ExecuteResult() method is not called in ASP.NET Web API 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am creating some custom action result as below.

```
public class MyActionResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Status = "my status";
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        context.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("MyHeader", "bingo");
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write("some content");
        context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

And my action method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("check/{id}")]
public MyActionResult Check(string id)
{
    return new MyActionResult();
}
```

I set a breakpoint in the ExecuteResult() but it never hit. And I test the Web API like this:

```
http://localhost:22247/api/v1/check/123
```

**I was expecting to see the content, header, etc I set in the ExecuteResult() method. But the actual result is always a JSON file with empty content like below. And the status code is always 200.**

```
{}
```

Why the ExecuteResult() method is not executed?

Comment: You have and attribute routing there, shouldn't your url be something like: `http://localhost:22247/api/v1/check/123`? Have you tried putting breakpoint inside action method? Does it get hit?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. I updated my test url. I put a breakpoint in the action method and it got hit.

Comment: The ActionResult is from the System.Web.MVC namespace. It seems it doesn't work well with System.Web.Http namespace, which is where Web API resides. I changed to create a custom result by deriving from the System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult, the ExecuteAsyc() method get executed.

Comment: Good point. Here is the [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/action-results) on action results in Web Api 2

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Yes, that's exactly the article I just read. :)

Comment: Well, I guess `IHttpActionResult` is your choice then. Or `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: HttpResponseMessage seems a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API borrowed some ideas from ASP.NET MVC and duplicated some type names from ASP.NET MVC namespaces. But Web API is totally different beast from ASP.NET MVC. They shouldn't be used in a naive mixing way.